# xslt format-number decimal, number less than one

Tags: xslt, format, numbers

I have this as input called $material_price:

```
2.40
1000
0.60
```

They run through

```
<!-- setup currency rendering -->
<xsl:decimal-format name="dkk" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($material_price, '#.###,00', 'dkk')"/>
```

Output is:

```
2,40
1.000,00
,60
```

How can I make changes to the xslt so last output is 0,60 and not ,60 (without the zero)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($material_price, '#.##0,00', 'dkk')"/>
```

The second parameter (picture string) is described as follows by the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_formatnumber.asp).

> Required. Specifies the format pattern. Here are some of the characters used in the formatting pattern:
>
> - 0 (Digit)
> - ## (Digit, zero shows as absent)
> - . (The position of the decimal point Example: ###.##)
> - , (The group separator for thousands. Example: ###,###.##)
> - % (Displays the number as a percentage. Example: ##%)
> - ; (Pattern separator. The first pattern will be used for positive numbers and the second for negative numbers)

Comment: Bingo! I have the feeling I ought to have figured that out my self, but couldn't. Thanks for your help.